# SeekBar with thumb - obscured by view above

Tags: android, layout, seekbar, exoplayer

I want to implement a layout with SeekBar (controller of audio playback) that is thin - meaning only the vertical progress line is visible and the thumb view should be above the top and bottom view. Unfortunately the part of the thumb gets obscured by the above view. 
My view looks like below:

[image]
Below is the layout schema of my Activity.

[image: Activity schema]

Comment: Is it obscured by the view above it? Or is the MediaPlayerFragment clipping its views to its own bounds?

Comment: I guess tge 2nd option. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
progressbar.bringToFront();
progressbar.invalidate();
```

If this does not work, set 
a top margin `1dp` or `2dp` for the progressbar, or  
a top padding `1dp` or `2dp` for the parent layout of the progressbar.